# mi left-sidebar no funciona bootstrap

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap

Hola buenos días tengan todos ustedes, tengo un problema con el left sidebar de bootstrap pasa que al hacer mas pequeño se hace para abajo pero no se oculta lo que quiero hacer es que al ocultarse me muestre las opciones en la parte superior del nav, ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esa pequeña parte? gracias por su atención que tengan buen día.

**Asi me aparece**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo esta asi:

```
<div class="left-sidebar">
    <div class="brand">
        <a href="<?= base_url() ?>" class="logo">
            <span>
                <img src="<?= base_url('assets/images/boxni.png') ?>" height="50px" alt="logo-small" class="">
            </span>
            <span>
                <img src="<?= base_url('assets/images/BOXNI_NOMBRE.png') ?>" alt="logo-large" class="logo-lg logo-dark" height="100">
                <img src="<?= base_url('assets/images/BOXNI_NOMBRE.png') ?>" alt="logo-large" class="logo-lg logo-light" height="100">
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-content">
        <div class="menu-body navbar-vertical tab-content">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="sidebarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="menu-label mt-0">P<span>rincipal</span></li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="<?= base_url('inicio') ?>"><i class="ti ti-smart-home menu-icon"></i><span>Inicio</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="<?= base_url('mascotas') ?>"><i class="mdi mdi-dog menu-icon"></i><span>Mis mascotas</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="<?= base_url('citas') ?>"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar-text-outline menu-icon"></i><span>Mis citas</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```